# Simplifying many if-statements

Tags: python, if-statement, simplify, simplification

Is there a way to simplify this pile of if-statements? This parsing function sure works (with the right dictionaries), but it has to test 6 if-statements for each word in the input. For a 5-word sentence that would be 30 if-statements. It is also kind of hard to read.

```
def parse(text):
    predicate=False
    directObjectAdjective=False
    directObject=False
    preposition=False
    indirectObjectAdjective=False
    indirectObject=False
    text=text.casefold()
    text=text.split()
    for word in text:
        if not predicate:
            if word in predicateDict:
                predicate=predicateDict[word]
                continue
        if not directObjectAdjective:
            if word in adjectiveDict:
                directObjectAdjective=adjectiveDict[word]
                continue
        if not directObject:
            if word in objectDict:
                directObject=objectDict[word]
                continue
        if not preposition:
            if word in prepositionDict:
                preposition=prepositionDict[word]
                continue
        if not indirectObjectAdjective:
            if word in adjectiveDict:
                indirectObjectAdjective=adjectiveDict[word]
                continue
        if not indirectObject:
            if word in objectDict:
                indirectObject=objectDict[word]
                continue
    if not directObject and directObjectAdjective:
        directObject=directObjectAdjective
        directObjectAdjective=False
    if not indirectObject and indirectObjectAdjective:
        indirectObject=indirectObjectAdjective
        indirectObjectAdjective=False
    return [predicate,directObjectAdjective,directObject,preposition,indirectObjectAdjective,indirectObject]
```

Here's also a sample of a dictionary, if that's needed.

```
predicateDict={
"grab":"take",
"pick":"take",
"collect":"take",
"acquire":"take",
"snag":"take",
"gather":"take",
"attain":"take",
"capture":"take",
"take":"take"}
```

Comment: Does a switch statement work for your use case?
https://jaxenter.com/implement-switch-case-statement-python-138315.html

Comment: This pattern "if not something: if not word in someDict: something = someDict[word]" could be turned into a function.

Comment: From the performance side if you want only if to be executed then use `elif` rather than series of `if`

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a Code Review question than a Stack Overflow one. A major issue is that you have similar data that you're keeping in separate variables. If you combine your variables, then you can iterate over them.

```
missing_parts_of_speech = ["predicate", [...]]
dict_look_up = {"predicate":predicateDict,
           [...]           
        }    
found_parts_of_speech = {}    
for word in text:
    for part in missing_parts_of_speech:
        if word in dict_look_up[part]:
            found_parts_of_speech[part] = dict_look_up[part][word]
            missing_parts_of_speech.remove(part)
            continue
```

Comment: Basically the same as my idea, but using three dicts/lists instead of just one might indeed be better.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to simply use the method [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). This method has the optional argument `default`. By passing this argument you can avoid a `KeyError`. If the key is not present in a dictionary, the default value will be returned.

If you use the previously assigned variable as default, it will not be replaced by an arbitrary value, but the correct value. E.g., if the current word is a "predicate" the "direct object" will be replaced by the value that was already stored in the variable.

---

**CODE**

```
def parse(text):
    predicate = False
    directObjectAdjective = False
    directObject = False
    preposition = False
    indirectObjectAdjective = False
    indirectObject = False

    text=text.casefold()
    text=text.split()
    for word in text:
        predicate = predicateDict.get(word, predicate)
        directObjectAdjective = adjectiveDict.get(word, directObjectAdjective)
        directObject = objectDict.get(word, directObject)
        preposition = prepositionDict.get(word, preposition)
        indirectObjectAdjective = adjectiveDict.get(word, indirectObjectAdjective)
        indirectObject = objectDict.get(word, indirectObject)

    if not directObject and directObjectAdjective:
        directObject = directObjectAdjective
        directObjectAdjective = False

    if not indirectObject and indirectObjectAdjective:
        indirectObject = indirectObjectAdjective
        indirectObjectAdjective = False

    return [predicate, directObjectAdjective, directObject, preposition, indirectObjectAdjective, indirectObject]
```

---

PS: Use a little more spaces. Readers will thank you...

---

PPS: I have not tested this, for I do not have such dictionaries at hand.

---

**PPPS: This will always return the *last* occurances of the types within the text, while your implementation will always return the *first* occurances.**

Answer (score 1):

You could map the different kinds of words (as strings) to dictionaries where to find those words, and then just check which of those have not been found yet and look them up if they are in those dicts.

```
needed = {"predicate": predicateDict,
          "directObjectAdjective": adjectiveDict,
          "directObject": objectDict,
          "preposition": prepositionDict,
          "indirectObjectAdjective": adjectiveDict,
          "indirectObject": objectDict}

for word in text:
    for kind in needed:
        if isinstance(needed[kind], dict) and word in needed[kind]:
            needed[kind] = needed[kind][word]
            continue
```

In the end (and in each step on the way) all the items in `needed` that do not have a `dict` as a value have been found and replaced by the value from their respective `dict`.

(In retrospect, it might make more sense to ue two dictionaries, or one dict and a set: One for the final value for that kind of word, and one for whether they have already been found. Would probably be a bit easier to grasp.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a new pattern to write this code instead the old one. The new pattern has 9 lines and  stay 9 lines - just add more dictionaries to D. The old has already 11 lines and will grow 4 lines with every additional dictionaries to test.

```
aDict = { "a1" : "aa1", "a2" : "aa1" }
bDict = { "b1" : "bb1", "b2" : "bb2" }
text = ["a1", "b2", "a2", "b1"]
# old pattern
a = False
b = False
for word in text:
    if not a:
        if word in aDict:
            a = aDict[word]
            continue
    if not b:
        if word in bDict:
            b = bDict[word]
            continue
print(a, b)
# new pattern
D = [ aDict, bDict]
A = [ False for _ in D]
for word in text:
    for i, a in enumerate(A):
        if not a:
            if word in D[i]:
                A[i] = D[i][word]
                continue
print(A)
```